# Any free static code analyzer for PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, static-code-analysis

We are looking for a free tool that we can use for PL/SQL static code analysis. The only tool we could find was Toad for Oracle but it's a commercial tool. Before we invest on it, wanted to check for any alternatives that are free.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toad for Oracle DOES have a free trial edition, if you want to try out before you purchase. But you need to get the Professional Edition for you to get CodeXpert which is the PL/SQL scanner. It was pretty decent and well integrated with Toad IDE.

If you are looking for a completely free edition you can try out [SonarCube](http://www.sonarqube.org/). But not sure if that uses CodeExpert underneath.

There's another free tool called [Manduka](http://www.manduka.tech/#/home) which is also a Pl/SQL scanner but not yet integrated with any IDE.

Comment: Manduka seems to produce only XML reports. HTML reports or IDE integration would have been nice.

Comment: I've just tried Manduka. I wasn't impressed as it threw up some false positives immediately.

Comment: We were ok with the issues it captured, however we would have preferred HMTL reports. They are pretty new i believe just released last week. Maybe you should start a discussion in their Google group regarding the problem you faced.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check out SonarQube which has support for PL/SQL. But not sure whether the PL/SQL plugin for Sonar is free.

Comment: We looked at SonarQube, their PL/SQL plugin is not free :(

Comment: There is an open source plugin for PL/SQL which might help you: https://github.com/felipebz/zpa